# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

Tags: grails

I am getting this error on running my grails 3.3.6 app. Not sure i understand what this error means.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:448)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a9f8fad3.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$34()
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a9f8fad3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7b54997c.invoke()
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a9f8fad3.resourceHandlerMapping()
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 24 common frames omitted

---

Will appreciate any lead towards the cause of this error.

Thanks
Shiraz

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: THe error message as in the above stacktrace is "No ServletContext set"